# Haskell getting IO list elements

Tags: list, haskell, io, element, monads

I have a type synonym **Card** consisting of a tuple. I also have a type synonym **Deck** defined as [Card] (a list of cards).

Due to a file read, I am stuck with the IO monad, specifically, I have an object with the type IO Deck. How would I retrieve the individual elements of the card list? Because of the IO monad, the type doesn't seem to be a list anymore so I cannot use the !! operator.

Comment: `fmap (!!x) ioDeck` - or `ioDeck >>= (\deck -> do some stuff with the deck)`

Comment: You can find out how to manipulate monads here: http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your main problem here is you simply don't know how to manipulate monads, so here are a few pointers:

Monads have a few functions to allow them to be manipulated. These stem from the basic ones defined in the monad typeclass, `return` and `>>=` (aka 'bind').

`return` allows a monad to be constructed, and `>>=` takes first a monad, then a function which constructs a monad, and applies the function to the value given. This is the way in which you would use it in your case:

```
-- Imagine your list to be here:
ioList :: IO [Int]
ioList = return [1,2,3,4,5]

-- If we were to print the second element...
main = ioList >>= ( \a -> return (a !! 1) ) >>= print

-- We could write this in do-notation, syntactic sugar for the above:
main = do
    list <- ioList
    print (list !! 1)
```

One could also use the function `liftM` from `Control.Monad` which takes a function and applies it to a monad like so:

```
import Control.Monad
main = print (liftM (!! 1) ioList)
```

You can find more ways to manipulate monads, as well as an explanation of the various type signatures involved, as well as do-notation and the rest [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads).

Comment: I think it's a bit misleading to say "manipulate monads". A monad is a once-and-for-all thing, a mathematical concept, you can't manipulate that! Nor can you manipulate _monadic values_ (aka _actions_; I think those are what you mean here). Operators like `>>=` don't manipulate but _combine_ such actions.

Comment: @leftaroundabout That's true, but at a beginner level, it may be a better idea to think about it in a more basic way that combining actions. I certainly find it easier to think in the former way.

Comment: How would you apply this to filtering?
I have _filter predicate iolist_ where iolist is the IO Deck and the predicate is Card -> Bool.
I tried using liftM but it didn't work.

Comment: @wolx it should work fine if you do `liftM (filter predicate) ioList` - it works like that for me. Your issue may be that you haven't enclosed the function as I have within parentheses. You will also need to import `Control.Monad`, where `liftM` comes from.

Comment: Nevermind, I managed by using fmap. :)
_fmap (filter predicate) iolist_ **Edit**: You beat me to it. Thank you again!

Comment: `sndElem <- list !! 1` won't work because `!!` doesn't return a monadic value.

Answer (score 1):

You should separate the code that you use for loading the deck from the game itself and then combine the two together somewhere. A template could be:

```
import System.Environment (getArgs)

solve :: Deck -> Deck
solve deck = -- do something here

loadDeckFromFile :: FilePath -> IO Deck
loadDeckFromFile fp = -- load deck code here

main :: IO ()
main = do
  deckFile <- fmap head getArgs
  deck <- loadDeckFromFile deckFile
  let solvedDeck = solve deck

  putStrLn "Starting deck:"
  print deck
  putStrLn "\nSolved deck:"
  print solvedDeck
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these are your types:

```
type Card = (Int, Int)

type Deck = [Card]

someDeck :: IO Deck
someDeck = undefined -- Some sample IO Deck which you have (from reading file etc.)
```

Then you can use the monad do-notation to access the `Deck`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

testFun :: IO Deck
testFun = do
  (x :: Deck) <- someDeck
  -- Operate here on the x value                 
  return []
```

The `<-` will extract the `Deck` from the `IO Deck`. Notice that the `x` is of type `Deck` here. You can apply your pure functions on that in an let expression. Another way would be to use `fmap` which is much simpler but less intuitive unless you are used to it.